# Systemd Timer has no trigger

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

My systemd timer is configured the following way which should execute its service every 5 minutes.

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync mail

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/5
Unit=mail.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the timer status is:

```
● mail.timer - Sync mail
     Loaded: loaded (/home/phil/.config/systemd/user/mail.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-06-12 09:49:05 CEST; 15min ago
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● mail.service

Jun 12 09:49:05 arch systemd[396]: Started Sync mail.
```

It has only triggered once and after that has no trigger. Any suggestions why that is the case?

Answer (score 3):

The timer will say `Trigger: n/a` as long as the unit it triggers is still running.  It will not attempt to schedule a service service which is already running. The timer trigger will be set for the next appropriate time when the service stops.

If it takes 12 minutes for your mail.service to execute, the timer will trigger it once, the service will execute for 12 minutes, then the timer will schedule it 3 minutes later, causing 15 minutes between the calls.

So, the answer is "be patient".  When `mail.service` completes, then it will start again at the next 5 min timepoint.

---

Here's an example:

```
# mytime.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 10

# mytime.timer
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/1
```

When I `systemctl start mytime.timer` we will see this:

```
$ systemctl --user status mytime.timer mytime.service
● mytime.timer - Test timer
     Active: active (waiting) since Sat 2021-06-12 10:56:01 CEST; 725ms ago
    Trigger: Sat 2021-06-12 10:57:00 CEST; 59s left

● mytime.service
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

While the service is executing, we will see:

```
$ systemctl --user status mytime.timer mytime.service
● mytime.timer - Test timer
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-06-12 10:56:01 CEST; 1min ago
    Trigger: n/a

● mytime.service
     Active: activating (start) since Sat 2021-06-12 10:57:00 CEST; 10ms ago
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/mytime.service
             └─11346 /bin/sleep 10
```

Once `sleep 10` has exited, the trigger will be set:

```
$ systemctl --user status mytime.timer mytime.service
● mytime.timer - Test timer
     Active: active (waiting) since Sat 2021-06-12 10:56:01 CEST; 1min 11s ago
    Trigger: Sat 2021-06-12 10:58:00 CEST; 49s left

● mytime.service
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2021-06-12 10:57:10 CEST; 1s ago
    Process: 11346 ExecStart=/bin/sleep 10 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```